# Simple way to tell which ports is SQL Server is running on using SQLCMD?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 Sql server instances on my machine, but I don't recall which port each is running on.  I can run the config manager to find this, but is there an easier way to do it from SQLCMD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will return the TCP port used.

```
SELECT
    e.name as ProtocolName
    ,ec.local_tcp_port as Port
    ,ec.local_net_address as IP
FROM
    sys.endpoints e
LEFT JOIN
    sys.dm_exec_connections ec
ON
    ec.endpoint_id = e.endpoint_id
where
      e.name = 'TSQL Default TCP'
GROUP BY
    e.name
    ,ec.local_tcp_port
    ,ec.local_net_address
```